# Correct use of scanf() in C, wrong output

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I am trying to design a program that calculates the average of any desired number of floats, until EOF. The program should also check if the input was correct and return "Wrong Input" when e.g. entering a string. The code I wrote works, but it gives wrong ouputs for the average. Can anyone tell me why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int times = 0;
    float sum = 0;
    float scan;
    float avrg;
    int scanvalue = 1;       
    while (scanvalue == 1) {             
        scanvalue = scanf("%f", &scan);
        sum = sum + scan;
        times++;                
    }    
    if (scanvalue == EOF) {
        avrg = sum / times;
        printf("The average is  %f\n", avrg);
    } else {
        printf("Wrong input");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Could you give an example input and output?

Comment: I would suspect, *incorrect use of `scanf()` correct output*, which in turn was of course **unexpected**.

Comment: What is your system and compiler? What key do you stroke to end the input?

Comment: `if(scanvalue==EOF)`  EOF is not necessarily 0.

Comment: Please note that being consistent with your coding style will pay off in the future, because if you develop such habit you will write higher quality code JUST BECAUSE OF THAT.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: OP is not comparing `EOF` with `0`, is comparing `EOF` with the return of the last `scanf`

Comment: @KeineLust _"The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs
before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the
number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
the event of an early matching failure."_

Answer (score 4):

You don't check `scanvalue` after `scanf()` and still use the value at `scan` which is messing up the average. Note that when `scanf()` returns `EOF` it will not modify `scan`, and thus it will still have its last value so you are adding the last value twice.

But if you enter invalid input at the beginning then the behavior is undefined, change it to

```
while ((result = scanf("%f", &value)) == 1) {
}
```

Also, I deliberately changed the names of your variables to illustrate a better way of naming them.

Comment: Thank you! However: why do I need the parenthesis inside and cannot write just while (result = scanf("%f", &value)== 1). I thought the compiler is reading such statements from left to right.

Comment: 1. Opearator precedence. 2. Because you can also go out to the street naked but you still wear clothes. 3. Because it becomes ambigous for human readers. 4. Because it's very ugly. 5. Really, because it looks horrible. 6. Because it looking bad, makes reading it difficult. But most impportantly, operator precedence.

Comment: "Note that when `scanf()` returns `EOF` it will not modify `scan`" is better as "Note that when `scanf()` returns less than 1 it will not modify `scan`".  Yet even that is not completely correct.  On the rare input error, `scanf()`, may return `EOF` and have changed `scan`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check scanvalue after the scanf, otherwise times will be incremented even if you enter EOF and sum will get a wrong input, thus resulting the average being wrong/messed.

So you should change

```
while (scanvalue == 1) {             
    scanvalue = scanf("%f", &scan);
    sum = sum + scan;
    times++;                
}
```

To

```
while (scanvalue == 1) {
    scanvalue = scanf("%f", &scan);
    if (scanvalue != 1)
      break;
    sum = sum + scan;
    times++;
}
```

Comment: Better to use `if (scanvalue != 1)
      break;`

Comment: `While (true)` will do

Comment: The loop written like that is clumsy compared with combining the assignment and test in the `while` loop condition.  It is not idiomatic C.